# Prevent adding to a public Dictionary

Tags: c#

I have a public dictionnary within a public class as follow:

```
namespace ApiAssembly
{
    public static class TypeStore
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes static members of the <see cref="TypeStore"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        static TypeStore()
        {
            Store = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the store.
        /// </summary>
        public static Dictionary<string, Type> Store { get; }

        public void AddTypes()
        {
            // This should be allowed
            TypeStore.Store.Add("object", typeof(object));
        }
    }
}
```

I want to prevent adding new elements to this dictionnary except internally (managed through API). What is the best way to achieve this?

```
namespace ClientAssembly
{
    using ApiAssembly;

    public class Client
    {
        public void AddTypes()
        {
            // How to prevent this call?
            TypeStore.Store.Add("object", typeof(object));
        }
    }
}
```

The content of the Dictionnary must be publicly accessible, so just flipping the access modifier is not an option

Comment: Make it private. Provide a method `GetType` that takes the key and returns the `Type`. Don't reveal the dictionary itself.

Comment: because I want the content to be publicly accessible. The types are generated within the API. The client assembly can access them and create instances but should not be adding its own types to the store

Comment: make it private and add a member function for `AddToDic` and `RemoveFromDic` (if you care). If you want consumers be able to acsess content of it, add another function `Type Find(string key)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expose it as:

```
IReadOnlyDictionary<string, Type> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
```

Or additionally use `ReadOnlyDictionary` wrapper to prevent casting back to `Dictionary`.

Full example:

```
public static class TypeStore
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Type> store;

    private static ReadOnlyDictionary<string, Type> storeReadOnly ;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes static members of the <see cref="TypeStore"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    static TypeStore()
    {
        store = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
        storeReadOnly = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, Type>(store);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the store.
    /// </summary>
    public static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, Type> Store => storeReadOnly;

    public static void AddTypes()
    {
        // This should be allowed
        TypeStore.store.Add("object", typeof(object));
    }
}
```

Comment: Best to wrap it in a `new ReadOnlyDictionary(...)` so they can't just cast it back.

Comment: @Rawling If you're worried about a malicious user intentionally accessing the implementation details they know they aren't supposed to access then even `ReadOnly Dictionary` doesn't help, as they can still get the private property out of it and use it.  If you assume a caller of your method is intentionally trying to violate your API, there's nothing you can do to stop them, so it's not really meaningful to consider such users.  If you assume the user isn't intentionally violating your API, then an interface works just fine.

Comment: @Servy If LINQ bothers to do it, I'd try to do it myself.

Comment: @Rawling Which LINQ operator(s) are you referring to?  And what collections are you referring to that are wrapped in another object purely to prevent a caller from casting them to something else?

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou What do you mean? ReadOnlyDictionary preserves reference to original store.

Comment: @Servy trivial selected deliberately do not result in the original collection being returned as an `IEnumerable`, but wrap it in an iterator, specifically to hide it from the caller.

Comment: @arekzyla: never mind, I had a wrong variable name when testing it. Your answer is correct

Comment: @Rawling The whole design of the method is to return a new object.  That's not them going out of their way to *avoid* returning the value, it's them *not* going out of their way *to* return the value, given that the method typically *requires* creating a new object in order to function.  There's also a notable difference between how you handle *a parameter* provided to your method and *an internal implementation detail*.  That's not a situation of them going out of their way to intentionally create an object they otherwise wouldn't have just to prevent casting of an internal collection.

Answer (score 7):

You should separate the actual storage dictionary and the one you use for the outside world. An easy way would be:

```
private static Dictionary<string, Type> Storage { get; } = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

public static ReadOnlyDictionary<string, Type> Store 
              => new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, Type>(Storage);
```

Where `Storage` is the actual backing dictionary you can edit.

Or even better, expose the methods you want to have available through your class (it serves as a proxy), where you never grant external classes access to the dictionary itself.

Comment: Very useful thank you! Will just be a bit of memory overhead usage in my current scenario

Comment: It's not the most optimal version because you are constantly creating new wrapper object with each call.